# Determining the position of an object in motion on a $3D$ plane

Tags: calculus, physics

Expressed as $x,y,z...$

$P_1 = (0,0,0)$

$P_2 = (1000,2000,3000)$

I know the formula for distance:  $$d=\sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2- y_1)^2 + (z_2- z_1)^2}$$

How do I find out where the object is halfway through its flight?

I'm using mysql, so geometric solutions may be possible using lines.

Read here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54860047/mysql-determining-the-position-of-an-object-in-motion

Comment: I heavily formatted your question, there were many typos, please check if everything is as intended. :)

Comment: Everything looks right. Thank you!

Comment: you didn´t have the square root there, was it a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The midway $M$ point between $P=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $Q=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ is given by 
$$
M=\Big(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2},\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}   \Big).
$$

EDIT:

What is happening here is actually you calculate
$$
(x_1,y_1,z_1)+t\big((x_2,y_2,z_2)- (x_1,y_1,z_1)\big)
$$

where we chose $t=\frac{1}{2}$ above, you could pick anything you like.

EDIT:

Coordinates are given by

$$
\Big((1-t)x_1+tx_2,(1-t)y_1+ty_2,(1-t)z_1+tz_2   \Big)
$$

Comment: Thank you. So I can modify this to find the position based on duration, or would that be more complicated?

Comment: I don't believe I can. It needs to be able to factor time as well. I'll see if I can dig up the formula.

Comment: @JohnWarwick It is not hard let me edit

Comment: @JohnWarwick Understand?

Comment: Would we put the new equation in place of the "divided by 2"? Sorry I'm having a hard time copying the formula

Comment: @JohnWarwick the second expression decides the new coordinates, hmmm let me edit :D

Comment: $$
\Big(\frac{(1-t)x_1+tx_2}{2},\frac{(1-t)y_1+2y_2}{2},\frac{(1-t)z_1+tz_2}{2}   \Big)
$$

Comment: I ran this by a friend and he said this is all wrong. Should the Y section be corrected? Should everything be divided by 2?

Comment: @JohnWarwick OMG! Of course not! I copy pasted the previos part and forgot to remove the fractions. The "divided by two" comes from the part when you choose $t=1/2$

Comment: Should it be ty squared not 2y squared?

Comment: @JohnWarwick This is getting funny. But its good you are finding all the typos! ;) corrected

Comment: Thank you. I'll test this out tonight.